# Any simple way to get a list of data with certain elements and not counting the 0?

Tags: python

I have a question in a list of list, which contains 3 possible routes, for example:

`routes=[[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)],[(0, 1), (1, 0)],[(0, 2), (2, 0)]]`

position 0 concerns the depot. Now I would like to obtain a list of list that tells me which positions will be visited, without repeating and without counting the 0, for each route, that is, to obtain something similar:

`route_positions=[[1,2],[1],[2]]`

In other words, in `routes.index[0]`, I will have the position [1,2] to visit.

I've been trying to solve the problem as follows, but still without success. Something like:

```
route_positions=[]
for route in routes:
route_positions+=[x for x in route if x!=0]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you want a nudge getting started, what would you get if you took the last item in each tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if i understood your question properly but this could work:

```
route_positions=[]
for route in routes:
    route_position_inside=set()
    for route_node in route:
        route_position_inside.update([for content in route_node if content != 0])
    route_positions.append(route_position_inside)
```

Comment: Thanks @Don Corlijoni. It works. I noticed that using set() makes it easier because it removes the duplicates, while the list maintains. Let me ask, if I wanted to keep a list with the results of the form `route_positions=[[1,2],[1],[2]]` instead of set(), I could use list.extend, however would not remove the duplicates. Any suggestion?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MarceloAlves yeah you can use a set and before appending it, you convert it to a list with list(route_position_inside)

Comment: Nice @DonCorliJoni! It makes more sense and makes the job easier than working with lists beforehand. Thansk a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have an answer and mentioned comprehensions, I see no harm in suggesting this as an alternative way to approach the problem:

```py
routes=[
    [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)],
    [(0, 1), (1, 0)],
    [(0, 2), (2, 0)]
]

route_stops = [
    [
        segment[1]  # the second element of the tuple
        for segment
        in route
        if segment[1] != 0
    ]
    for route
    in routes
]

print(route_stops)
```

This should give you:

```
[[1, 2], [1], [2]]
```